# CodeBuild doesn't report failed tests

Tags: amazon-web-services, unit-testing, jestjs, aws-codebuild

I am using CodeBuild to build my NPM project. I have a report group specific in my buildspec and I am running unit tests using Jest and the `npm test` command.

When all the tests pass, they are reported to the CodeBuild report group successfully. However if one of the tests fails I get the error:

```
[Container] 2020/08/24 01:41:18 Phase context status code: COMMAND_EXECUTION_ERROR Message: Error while executing command: npm test -- --silent. Reason: exit status 1`
```

and the build stops (which is fine in general) but the failed test is not reported so the test pass rate remains at 100% and means I don't see test trends or other details.

The relavent parts of my buildspec.yml:

```
version: 0.2
phases:
  install:
    commands:  
      - npm install
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - npm test -- --silent    
reports:
  jest_reports:
    files:
      - 'test-results.xml'
    file-format: JunitXml
    base-directory: "reports/results"
```

The Jest config in my package.json:

```
"jest": {
    "reporters": [
        "default",
        [
            "jest-junit",
            {
                "outputDirectory": "reports/results",
                "outputName": "test-results.xml"
            }
        ]
    ]
}
```

The final part of the CodeBuild log:

```
Test Suites: 1 failed, 8 passed, 9 total
Tests:       2 failed, 57 passed, 59 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        3.034s
npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.

[Container] 2020/08/24 01:41:18 Command did not exit successfully npm test -- --silent exit status 1
[Container] 2020/08/24 01:41:18 Phase complete: PRE_BUILD State: FAILED
[Container] 2020/08/24 01:41:18 Phase context status code: COMMAND_EXECUTION_ERROR Message: Error while executing command: npm test -- --silent. Reason: exit status 1
```

How can I setup CodeBuild to report failed tests, but still prevent it from continuing the build if a test does fail?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In researching this, all of the examples that I see that use CodeBuild test reports, the tests are run as part of the `build` phase.

Since your tests are in the `pre_build` phase, if the `pre_build` fails, it won't proceed to the `upload_artifacts` phase and will just skip to `finalizing`.  [See the CodeBuild phase transitions diagram for more information on this.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/view-build-details.html#view-build-details-phases)

I'd recommend following the patterns of the user guides and putting your tests in the `build` phase.

User guide references:

- https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/test-reports-with-aws-codebuild/
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/sample-test-report-cli.html

Comment: Huh, interesting. Moving my tests into the `build` phase works as when the test fails, the build stops but still runs the `post_build` phase in which the test report is generated and uploaded. The [serverless tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codestar/latest/userguide/sam-tutorial.html) and this [example](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sam-cli-app-templates/blob/master/nodejs12.x/cookiecutter-quick-start-from-scratch/%7B%7Bcookiecutter.project_name%7D%7D/buildspec.yml) show the tests running in `pre_build`, which is honestly where it makes sense to be run.

Comment: I found the [CodeBuild transitions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/view-build-details.html#view-build-details-phases) page which shows that failures before the `build` phase go to `finalising` while failures during `build` continue to `post_build`, which is where reports and artifacts are uploaded. Chalk it up to another poor AWS documentation I guess.

Comment: I updated my answer to reference the diagram you found, we both are learning! :)