# AWS not stopping when unitest fails in the codebuild

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild, aws-code-deploy

I am doing a very simple CI/CD using codepipeline with (codeCommit, codebuild, codeDeploy).

I have a simple node.js app that has a unittest like this below

```
const Allsayings = require('./testAllsayings');
function logPass(tName){
    console.log("PASS - " + tName);
}
function logFail(tName){
    console.log("FAIL - " + tName )
}
// T01 - Search for a saying and succeed
let say01 = new Allsayings();
say01.addQuote("Everyone is looking for something.");
say01.addQuote("Let's try to figure this out together, so help me please");
let output01 = aq01.findSaying("Not here");
if (output01.search("Before you embark") > -1){
    logPass("T01");
} else {
    logFail("T01");
}
```

**I want that when the unit test fails it halt/stop the deployment or the progression of the pipeline.**

my byuildspec

```
version: 0.2
phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions:
      nodejs: 16
    commands:
      - echo Installing
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - echo Installing source NPM dependencies.
      - cd serverSide
      - npm install
  build:
    commands:
      - echo Build started on `date`
      - npm install pm2@latest -g
        # buildspec is able to get into your servSide file?
      - ls
      - echo "for debugging ... starting test"
      - node testAllsayings.js
      - echo "test is successful ... "
  post_build:
    commands:
      - echo Build completed on `date`
artifacts:
  files:
    - '**/*'
```

However, my problem is that when I run codepipeline the codebuild completes successfully despite I made my unittest fail and here is a part of the codebuild log

```
[Container] 2022/10/03 00:45:05 Running command echo "for debugging ... starting test"
for debugging ... starting test

[Container] 2022/10/03 00:45:05 Running command node testAllsayings.js
Fail - T01


[Container] 2022/10/03 00:45:05 Running command echo "test is successful ... "
test is successful ...
```

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63553921/codebuild-doesnt-report-failed-tests), and I moved the command  `node testAllsayings.js` to the pre_build stage, but still everything worked without stopping the build stage or deployment stage.

Comment: Hey, do you know how can I make aws build pipeline to run on ec2 instance?

Comment: Can you be more clear! Are you asking about codeBuild or codePipeline?

Comment: Any of the service works..My use case is I have a tosca machine installed on ec2..I have to make my code build pipeline to either run on that ec2 instance to communicate with tosca and run some CMD line tasks to execute scripts..am not sure if I can register ec2 machine as build agent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found a solution. For code build to catch the error from the unittest, the function has to exist with one. So I added this line of code and now code build stops when the unittest fails.

```
function logFail(tName){
    console.log("FAIL - " + tName )
      process.exitCode(1);

}
```